# Definite article

Tags: grammaire

I want to say the sentence below in French:

> My parents are American.

Why is it translated as "*Mes parents sont Américains*"?

Why it is not "*Mes parents sont les Américains*"?

Comment: [correction: I want to say the sentence below in French.]

Comment: Would you say *My parents are the American* ? Same.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence:

> My parents are American

the word *American* is an **adjective**, so it has to be in the french sentence.

When you say:

> Mes parents sont les Américains

we tend to understand that your parents are all the american people, which I think is not the case ! This is because by adding *les* which is a definite article, *Américains* becomes a noun.

---

To finish i will add that, at least for me, it's more common to see written *Mes parents sont **a**méricains* than *Mes parents sont **A**méricains*.

When nominating people from a country, we have to put an uppercase. For example, you would say (uppercase):

> Les **F**rançais aiment manger du pain.

Nevertheless, adjectives do not take uppercases. (no uppercase):

> Je préfère le pain **f**rançais.

There is kind of a debate to know wether or not "Mes parents sont Américains" needs uppercase or not.

Answer (score 1):

*Mes parents sont les Américains* only make sense if there are pair of parents, on a list or whatever, only one of which is composed of American people.

For example:

> *Le journal a interviewé des parents de diverses nationalités. Il y avait un couple d'Anglais, un couple de Canadiens, un couple d'Australiens et un couple d'Américains. Mes parents sont les Américains.*

Here, the meaning is "My parents are the American ones".

If you just want to say that your parents are American, that's *mes parents sont américains* (or *Américains*, your choice.)